# How to get written data from a txt file

Tags: python

I am attempting to make some code that will take a persons height, convert it into feet and store it in a txt file.

```
def rollercoaster():
  name = input("what is your name?: ")
  heightCM = int(input("enter your height in cm: "))
  ft = (heightCM / 30.48)
  print(f"you are {ft} foot tall.")
  if ft < 5.5:
    booklist = open("booklist.txt", "a")
    booklist.write(name)
    booklist.write(" ")
    booklist.write("NOT TALL ENOUGH.")
    booklist.close()
  if ft > 5.5:
    booklist = open("booklist.txt", "a")
    booklist.write(name)
    booklist.write(" ")
    booklist.write("TALL ENOUGH.")
    booklist.close()
```

I would like to make it so if your name that you input is already in the txt file, it will see if you're tall enough for the rollercoaster.

Comment: so you want to skipt the whole process if the name is already in the file?

(it would be easier to use something other than a .txt, like a .json)

Comment: You should add a newline after each line. Then read the file line by line, and check if the line begins with their name.

Comment: You could use JSON instead of txt like @ 
Mahrkeenerh said and load it to a dictionary, then you'll be able to lookup for names and their associated values, like height. `import json` and `json.load("file.json")`.

Comment: Thank you! now all there's left to do is figure out how to say to python "if the users input name is the same as the txt file name, print this..."

Answer (score 0):

Open your file and scan it for the names. Otherwise, append.

```
def rollercoaster():
  name = input("what is your name?: ")
  heightCM = int(input("enter your height in cm: "))
  ft = (heightCM / 30.48)
  print(f"you are {ft} foot tall.")
  found = None
  with open("booklist.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
          if line.startswith(name):
              found = line
              break
  if found is not None:
      print(found)  
  else:
      with open("booklist.txt", "a") as booklist:
          if ft < 5.5:
              booklist.write(f'{name} NOT TALL ENOUGH\n')   
          else:
              booklist.write(f'{name} TALL ENOUGH\n')
```

---

However, as mentioned in the comments, JSON would make more sense than scanning lines.

For example, mapping names to heights (in cm)

```
{
  "alice": 158, 
  "bob": 172 
}
```

Then read that, and perform the conversion and check if they are tall enough or not (there is no need to store whether or not they are tall enough in the file itself).